# Selectable Points of vector layer have an offset

Tags: openlayers-3

I've got a vector layer with a GeoJSON source, consisting of Points and a LineString. When I click on a point I want to open a popup with additional information.

Here's some code:

```
var style = {
  'Point': [new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgb(255,0,0)'
      }),
      radius: 5,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#000000',
        width: 1
      }),
    })
  })],
  'LineString': [new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#ff0000',
      width: 3
    })
  })],
  'MultiLineString': [new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#0000ff',
      width: 3
    })
  })]
};


var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map-ol-canvas',
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({mouseWheelZoom: false}),
  layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() })],
  view: new ol.View({
    zoom: 8,
    maxZoom: 16
  })
});
map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());

var trackSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: '/test.geojson',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});

var track = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: trackSource,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    return style[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
  }
});
map.addLayer(track);

var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
  filter: function (feature, layer) {
    return feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point';
  }
});
map.addInteraction(select);
      
// When user clicks on a waypoint, show a tooltip.
function onMouseClick(browserEvent) {
  var coordinate = browserEvent.coordinate;
  var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate);
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
    if (feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {
      console.log(feature.get('date'));
    }
  });
}
map.on('click', onMouseClick);
```

**The problem:**

When I click directly on a point nothing happens. When I click a couple of pixels below and a bit right or left (depends on zoom level!), the point gets selected and the console.log is triggered.

I can fix this by using Firebox WebDeveloper Addon and activating "Disable all styles".
However, when I manually remove all CSS one by one that behavior never goes away.
In the first place I thought this might be some inherited padding or margin, but currently I think the canvas shouldn't be affected by any CSS at all.

Any ideas about what could be wrong?

Comment: Why do you need an `ol.interaction.Select` with a `filter`? You are already checking inside `onMouseClick`.

Comment: This is just to see if the offset appears on both interactions. It does ;)

Comment: Have you try setting the snaptoPixel option to false ? http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.style.Circle.html

Comment: I wasn't away of this option. But sadly, it didn't fix the issue. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue. It appears to be linked to navigating to the page from a specific modal (I'm using ajax hash paging). The footer doesn't load and after I interact with the first feature on the map the following happens;

1. The map jumps and stretches/smears slightly
2. The footer shows up on my page
3. The vertical scroll bar appears

The issue doesn't seem to occur when i link from another page.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.Here are some advices may help you:

1. check the the size of map's container(may be a Div).
2. check the size of map(openlayers's map object).
3. compare that two size to confirm whether the two size are equal.

if not, you can use the `map.setSize([width,height])`to adjust the map's size.

Comment: ps: map's size mean the openlayers map object,not the mapDiv's size.